# Wordpress conditional tag to identify if custom header.php is used

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, custom-post-type

I am looking for a solution to identifying **ONLY ONE PAGE (4 in the list below)** with conditional statement when using `add_rewrite_endpoint` on a custom `post-type`.

For example, let's say that I have four types of pages per the `post-type` **campaigns**...

1. campaigns/**post-title**/overview
2. campaigns/**post-title**/preview
3. campaigns/**post-title**/analytics
4. campaigns/**post-title** - As single-campaigns.php

using this code in a function

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'overview', EP_PERMALINK );
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'analytics', EP_PERMALINK );
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'preview-campaign', EP_PERMALINK );
```

Then calling on the seperate page-templates in single-campaigns.php with

```
if( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-overview.php");
} 
elseif( array_key_exists( 'analytics', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-analytics.php");
}
elseif( array_key_exists( 'preview-campaign', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    include("campaign-templates/single-campaign-preview.php");
}
else{
    get_header('landing');
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        if ( $post->post_content=="" ) {
           the_content(); 
        } else {
           the_content(); 
        };
    endwhile;
    endif; 
    get_footer('new');
}
```

Obviously, the use of `is_singular`, `is_single`, etc will identify and apply the condition to all page types of each post.

**My original idea was to add the condition to something to identifying the use of `get_header(landing)`, is this possible?**

EDIT -
To give more context. I am trying to apply the condition of `if` to only the single (#4 as shown in the list above) page and no others.

```
if ( **single-campaigns.php**() ) {
    //Function
}else{
    wp_register_script( 'wp_auth_check', '/wp-includes/js/wp-auth-check.js' , array('heartbeat'), false, 1);
...
}
```

Comment: `if ( $post->post_content=="" ) {
            echo the_content(); 
        } else {
            echo the_content(); 
        };`  :D And `the_content();` will print content automatically. You do not need use `echo`.

Comment: thanks @MaximSarandi. I notice that you have sent the same as the content above, any ideas to my issue of identifying the page in a seperate function?

Comment: Yes @MaximSarandi. Already know that - late here and was written in error. Not really what my question is regarding but thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all, what you needed. You created endpoints,create condition and check true for every single types. Create variables for template or header. And past to call `get_header()` or `get_template_part();`
May be something like this might help you

```
if ( array_key_exists( 'overview', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
    $template = 'overview';
    $header   = 'test';
} elseif ( array_key_exists( 'analytics', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
    $template = 'analytics';
    $header   = 'tes1';
} elseif ( array_key_exists( 'preview-campaign', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
    $template = 'preview-campaign';
    $header   = 'test2';
} else {
    $template = 'default';
    $header   = '';
}
```

...

```
get_header( $header );
```

...

```
get_template_part( '/parts/', $template );
```

Or create function to use in conditionals:

```
function is_single_with_endpoint( $endpoint ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( ! isset( $endpoint ) && ! empty( $endpoint ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( array_key_exists( $endpoint, $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if ( is_single_with_endpoint( 'overview' ) ) {
    // get_header or something
}
```

Comment: I like the second part of your answer and I think that is interesting. The only issue I face is that the page that I want to be contained in my `if` condition does not have a written endpoint. It is the default post page.

Comment: Use else in condition))

Comment: I know, but unfortunately it will then exclude other pages that are not a part of the post type. What I am in the basic trying to achieve is - add frontend admin scripts for `wp_auth_check` to every page, except for the single campaign page, which is the only publicly viewable page. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Your method and answer works great for identifying an endpoint against another endpoint but not outside of this.

Comment: I have condition. If your page has not any endpoints function will return false.

Comment: my hah? Not sure I understand.

Comment: I see but 90% of my other pages do not have endpoints but require the scripts added. This will ultimately add to every other page. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Anyhow, thank you for your time. I will have a play and apply this to my code to see if it can work. Cheers.

Comment: What’s wrong? Add your script if my function return you true. I

Comment: As I said, your answer works great if I want to condition out an endpoint. Yet, if I am trying to condition out a page without the endpoint it cannot work without affecting all pages, except those with an endpoint defined. So identifying the endpoint `overview` as in your example works but it is not the page I am trying to capture, thus not really answering the question. Returning false will effect more than the single page.